# Wifi light turns red but wireless still works when I close bluetooth on an HP DV6

Tags: 12.04, wireless, hp, hp-pavilion

I installed 12.04 and upgraded kernel to 3.6.1 . and now, when I close bluetooth on gnome, my wifi light turns red but wifi still works. I want to know how to fix it.

Ubuntu 12.04 
Kernel 3.6.1
Hp dv6-2160et

Thanks for helps

Comment: Help me! Somebody Help Me !

Comment: It sounds like everything works perfectly, just that the color of the light changes. Is this correct? If not, what exactly stops working? Also, why are you using the `3.6.1` kernel, and why do you 'close bluetooth in gnome'. I hope you can make the question clearer so that you can get a good answer. Right now, it is hard to see where there is even a problem.

Comment: actually it is true . why did  I raise it so ? . but if there any solution it will make me happy

Comment: The bluetooth and Wifi don't have anything to do with each other. If you switch of bluetooth, wifi *should* still work (and vice versa).

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo wifi light close/open wifi and bluetooth in hp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded new kernel with fresh install and update . problem solved

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block bluetooth or wifi you may use the `rfkill block wifi` or `rfkill block bluetooth` commands in a terminal. To block both you could try `rfkill block all`.

Comment: you had better read again all of question